# php foreach within foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, pdo

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to print the result like this:

```
Header 1
    Link 1
    Link 2
Header 2
    Link 3
Header 3
    Link 4
    Link 5
```

But the codes below is printing the result like this:

```
Header 1
    Link 1
    Link 2
Header 2
    Link 1
    Link 2
    Link 3
Header 3
    Link 1
    Link 2
    Link 3
    Link 4
    Link 5
```

Using the [php pdo wrapper class](http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/), as far as I know I have no choice but to use "foreach" instead of "while" to loop results, and here is my code:

```
$bind = array(":users_id" => $id);
$categoryQry = $db->select("category","users_id=:users_id", $bind);
//loop Headers
foreach($categoryQry AS $CatRes){
    $category_name = $CatRes['category_name'];

    $bind = array(
        ":users_id" => $id,
        ":link_category" => $CatRes['category_id']
    );
    $linkQry = $db->select("links", "users_id=:users_id AND link_category=:link_category", $bind);
    //loop Links under each header
    foreach($linkQry AS $LinkRes){
        $link_url = $LinkRes['link_url'];
        //$link_row outputs the links under each header, this is where the problem is        
        $link_row .= DisplayLayout("link_row.html","\$link_url");
    }

    //$header outputs the result OK (3 headers as stated in above example)    
    $header .= DisplayLayout("header.html","\$category_name,\$link_row");
}
//note that DisplayLayout is my template function which is used for outputting variables using an HTML file.
```

I have been trying few other methods with no luck, hopefully someone will spot the problem in my code and lead me to the right direction.

Thank you in advance and Merry Christmas.

Comment: $link_row is only ever added to, you need to empty it after each outer loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset $link_row just before this line: `foreach($linkQry AS $LinkRes)`

Comment: That's the logic side of thing I neglected.  Thanks for the pointer, that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$bind = array(":users_id" => $id);
$categoryQry = $db->select("category","users_id=:users_id", $bind);
//loop Headers
foreach($categoryQry AS $CatRes){
$category_name = $CatRes['category_name'];

$bind = array(
    ":users_id" => $id,
    ":link_category" => $CatRes['category_id']
);
$linkQry = $db->select("links", "users_id=:users_id AND link_category=:link_category", $bind);
//loop Links under each header
$link_row='';
foreach($linkQry AS $LinkRes){
    $link_url = $LinkRes['link_url'];
    //$link_row outputs the links under each header, this is where the problem is        
    $link_row .= DisplayLayout("link_row.html","\$link_url");
}

//$header outputs the result OK (3 headers as stated in above example)    
$header .= DisplayLayout("header.html","\$category_name,\$link_row");
}
//note that DisplayLayout is my template function which is used for outputting     variables using an HTML file.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//reset linkrow
$link_row = '';


foreach($linkQry AS $LinkRes){
    $link_url = $LinkRes['link_url'];
    //$link_row outputs the links under each header, this is where the problem is        
    $link_row .= DisplayLayout("link_row.html","\$link_url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

empty `$link_row` before 2nd loop.